# what does <bound method person.get_name of <__main__.person object at 0x02887790>> mean

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just wanted to know why I am getting this error in my program.
kinda new to python and Stackoverflow and i saw a type of bound method error somewhere else but did not quite understand it.

```
class person(object):

    def get_name(self):

        self.name=raw_input("what is your name?")
        ans=raw_input("your name is %s right?" %self.name)



        while ans=="no":
            name=raw_input("sorry about that what is your name then?")
            ans="yes"
        else:
            print ("nice to have you %s !!" %self.name)

bob= person()
bob.get_name()

print bob.get_name
```

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Answer (score 4):

You are not actually executing your method. You need to add the `()` to execute your method:

Change this:

```
print bob.get_name
```

to this

```
print bob.get_name()
```

What is meant by "bound" is that your method get_name is bound to the instance `person`:

```
<bound method person.get_name of <__main__.person object at 0x02887790>>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error; it's simply what `bob.get_name` looks like (that is, it's what you get when you print a method). You probably meant to print the return value of the method, for which you have to call it:

```
print bob.get_name()
```

(Note the `()`.)